# PHP function to easy display messages

Tags: php, function, echo

I am trying to make a function that will allow me to easy display messages in my pages using PHP.

My function:

```
/*
* Function to easy write modal / help boxes
*/
function modal($title, $message)
{
        echo '
        <!-- HELP MODAL -->
        <div style="display:none;">
            <div id="help" class="modal-content inline">
            <h3>'.$title.'</h3>
            '.$message.'
            </div>
        </div>
        <!-- END HELP MODAL -->         
        ';
}
```

And my PHP code:

```
<?php echo modal("Title Message","Message <br /> <a href='link'>link</a>"); ?>
```

This does not work. I have turned on error_reporting, but see no error.

What am I doing wrong?

Comment: Please edit your question to show the rendered HTML.

Comment: You're calling the function as `echo modal`; but modal doesn't return anything - it just echos text directly. It might not be causing the problem, but you should either return a string from the function, or not echo out the function call

Comment: @oliverbj - you just need to call `<?php modal("Title Message", ".....`

Comment: There is nothing wrong with the code you have shown here. The problem lies elsewhere. Paste the whole code.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try to `return` the echo statement from your modal function.

```
$text = '<div> Your div </div>';
return $text;
```

OR

Make a `exit` after echo statement in your modal function

```
echo '<div> Your div </div>';
exit;
```

Answer (score 1):

You have `display: none;` set as an attribute. Unless you have some client-script that changes this then your echoed HTML will never be visible to the user.

However if the HTML isn't being rendered in the first place (i.e. the calls to `echo` do nothing) then something is amiss, so please edit your question to show the rendered HTML.

Comment: Well, when I echo modal($titel, $message), I see nothing on the page. The HTML stops where that line is written..

Comment: I did. The HTML code stops where that php function is echoed.